# Positive minimum value in autonumeric.js

Tags: javascript

From the configurator page on http://autonumeric.org/configurator - I need to create a field with the '£' symbol, no decimal places and min value £25,000, max value 1 bn.

I tried the following but it won't let me enter anything in the the sample field at the top of the page ?

This should be straightforward or am I missing something ?

```
{
    currencySymbol: "£",
    decimalPlaces: 0,
    defaultValueOverride: "25000",
    maximumValue: "1000000000",
    minimumValue: "25000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the default value for input first. This value is between min and max value.
Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
[Codepen] https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGOpOj?editors=1010
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sadly this doesn't work. If you remove the value and try to enter 26,000 it won't accept the input

Comment: @Amj: You're right. I think it's the issue from autonumeric.js. Sorry can't help you better, my friend!